# How to handle no entity in database for entered parameters?

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to implement simple login system. I have a JSP with form where user enters username and password, and then servlet that is reading those parameters. You'll understand from servlet code:

```
User user = userDao.findUserWithUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
// user found
if (user!=null) {
    session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    loginMessage = "Welcome";
    request.setAttribute("loginMessage", loginMessage);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
} else // username and password not matching
    {
    loginMessage = "Wrong username or password! Please try again.";
    request.setAttribute("loginMessage", loginMessage);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

This works if I enter valid username and password, but if not I am getting next exception:

```
javax.persistence.NoResultException: Query "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE
u.username like :username AND u.password LIKE :password" selected no
result, but expected unique result.
```

What is the proper way of handling this situation? I would like for wrong username and password parameters to display appropriate message (forwarding in 'loginMessage' variable).

[added]This is the code in UserDAOBean:

```
@Stateless
@Local(UserDAOLocal.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class UserDAOBean extends GenericDAOBean<User, Integer> implements UserDAOLocal{

    public User findUserWithUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password)
    {
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("findUserWithUsernameAndPassword");
        q.setParameter("username", username);
        q.setParameter("password", password);
        User result = (User) q.getSingleResult();
        return result;
    }
}
```

And named query in entity User is:

> @NamedQuery(name = "findUserWithUsernameAndPassword", query = "SELECT
>   u FROM User u WHERE u.username like :username AND u.password LIKE
>   :password")

Comment: The problem seems to be in the implementation of `userDao.findUserWithUsernameAndPassword` which you haven't posted.

Comment: please add the code of the `userDao.findUserWithUsernameAndPassword` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Exception is throw by the entity manager when you call the method getSingleResult and there is no resul, so you need to change the findUserWithUsernameAndPassword method.
If you are searching the entity by it's Primary Key you could use the em.find, it method returns null if there is no result.
Another option is not use the getSingleResult() and use the getResultList() it will not throw the NoResultException if there is no result, you need to check if the list is empty if there is no result.

If you want to maintain your method you must to catch the Exception and implements the logic where there is no result.

Comment: Thanks, instead of getSingleResult i used getResultList:
 `List<User> resultList = (List<User>) q.getResultList();
  if (resultList.isEmpty())
   return null;
  else
   return resultList.get(0);
 }`